# In UIWebview the copy/paste menu is not visible

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uimenucontroller

If I set content inset to webview's scrollview, the native menu to copy/paste the text is not visible at all.  When content inset (bottom) exceeds particular value than popover to copy/paste does not appear.

Any help would be appreciated.